# Click Button/Dropdown using Colly | Golang

Tags: selenium, go, web-scraping, go-colly

Is there a way to "click" a button using colly in go?
I basically need scrape data from a dynamic website, e.g. "open a dropdown", klick on different options so that other parts of the website update.
This can be easily done using Python / Selenium but I would like to test colly.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

go-colly is a web scraper library, but you want to use it as an automated test tool.  I do see POST request handling in the go-colly code base, but it sounds like you're trying to use a wrench to drive a nail.  Why not just use the hammer and use selenium?  I see search results for golang selenium packages when I Google.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your answer makes sense. I will have a look